# Finding the most rented car of each year in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables as follows:

```
Car(id, make, ....)
Deal(id,datetime,car_id,....)
```

I want to write a query that would return a year, and a car make for the cars that have the most deals (ie the most deal ids) and the number of deals for that car make.

I started out,

```
SELECT YEAR(D.datetime) AS the_year, C.make, COUNT(D.id) AS num
FROM Deal D, Car C
WHERE D.car_id=C.id
GROUP BY the_year
```

Unfortunately, this has returned the year and the total number of deals. 
So I am thinking to create this within another table and then call `MAX(tbl.num)`, but I am confused on the syntax.
Can somebody help me out please?

Comment: Can you ORDER BY COUNT(D.id) DESC and LIMIT 1, then use that id to get the details for that car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  What you are looking for is specifically called the "mode" in statistics.  In MySQL, you would get this by using variables or the `group_conat()`/substring_index()` trick.  I'll show the latter:

```
SELECT the_year,
       substring_index(group_concat(cd.make order by num desc), ',', 1) as the_mark
FROM (SELECT YEAR(D.datetime) AS the_year, C.make, COUNT(D.id) AS num
      FROM Deal D JOIN
           Car C
           ON D.car_id = C.id
      GROUP BY the_year, c.make
     ) cd
GROUP BY the_year;
```

EDIT:

The version using variables:

```
SELECT the_year,
       substring_index(group_concat(cd.make order by num desc), ',', 1) as the_mark
FROM (SELECT YEAR(D.datetime) AS the_year, C.make, COUNT(D.id) AS num,
             @rn := if(@year = YEAR(D.datetime), @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @year := YEAR(D.datetime)
      FROM Deal D JOIN
           Car C
           ON D.car_id = C.id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @year := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      GROUP BY the_year, c.make
      ORDER BY the_year, num DESC
     ) cd
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thats an interesting way of writing it. Thank you for your help